# PL/SQL compiling anonymous block with calling subprograms

Tags: plsql

Sorry for maybe simple question, but I'm just novice with PL/SQL.

I have one file, in which is anonymous block on the first lines, next one procedure and one function 
at the end of the file. The procedure is called from function and function is called from anonymous block. How can I ensure to compile firstly procedure and function and after that compile and execute anonymous block?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. A function and Procedure are objects in the DB, after you compile them - they are there (until somebody drops them) - like a table. An anonymous block is like a batch of commands it gets *run* not *compiled*... So, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: So, what happens if someone changes something in that function? E.g. adds some update statements. Next, saves the file and runs. Because for me in this case it ends with error:
RA-06550: Line 23, column 13:
PLS-00905: object GLN.UPGRADE_TO_NEWER is invalid
PROCEDURE UPDATE_VERSION compiled
FUNCTION UPGRADE_TO_NEWER compiled

But next run ends correctly:
anonymous block completed
PROCEDURE UPDATE_VERSION compiled
FUNCTION UPGRADE_TO_NEWER compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be having a single SQL file with all these ananymous blocks, procedures and functions.

You must first take into account that PL/SQL anonymous blocks are never compiled and saved but are compiled and executed. You do not specify an object name for these blocks and this is why they are called anonymous. You cannot have any references in the data definition schema views about the anonymous blocks you have run. You can have information of your stored procedures and functions though in the data definition schema views, like `user_procedures`, `user_objects`, etc.

Second thing to take into account is that when there are dependencies in a multitude your procedures or functions, you must first try to compile the independent procedures or functions.

The steps can be as follows:

1. In your case, the independent objects seems to be your procedure. Compile it first.
2. Now your function is a dependent object that depends upon your procedure. Hence after compiling your procedure, compile the function.
3. And now, you can execute the anonymous block that refers to the function.

You just need to arrange the code in your SQL file such that the procedure comes first, the function next and the anonymous block at the end. You then just need to execute that script.

Comment: I would suggest for more information you should read Oracle's documentation on functional dependencies.